# How do natives understand which meaning of a tense is implied?

Tags: tenses

Some tenses may trigger different time aspects. For example, Present Perfect and Present Perfect Continuous may refer to one recent action or to a series of actions. How does one differ them?

- I have talked to Peter for 20 minutes.

May mean: 1) I have talked to Peter for 20 minutes more than once in my life. (repeated action) 2) I have talked to Peter for 20 minutes one time recently.

- Have you been waiting for me for a long time?

May mean: 1) A one-off recent action. 2) A repeated action.

Are there any guidelines or does it all come down to the context and experience in English?

Comment: Most of the shortcut guidelines you guys are taught do a poor job at conferring any understanding as to how and why native speakers really and truly use these constructions in real life. Those shortcuts are there simply to stop you from making terrible blunders. They aren’t very good for anything else.

Comment: If thinking of those as being said in conversation (idiomatic speech), I interpret both of them as referring to something ongoing in the present. *I've been talking to Peter for 20 minutes so far* and *How long have you been waiting for me?* Neither sentence sounds like something that would be used outside of dialogue.

Comment: You might be thinking more of the difference between 'I have crashed into my neighbour's car' and 'I have been crashing into my neighbour's car' or 'I have cut my arm' and 'I have been cutting my arm'. The first in each case is one completed action (perfect aspect) and in the second (continuous aspect) it's repeated and probably not healthy behaviour.

Comment: @Jason Bassford If a conversation starts with the question "Have you been waiting for me for a long time?" I think it might be interpreted in more than one way, no? Especially, when the addressee indeed hasn't been waiting.

Comment: @user1425 I can think of no scenario in which somebody would ever ask *Have you been waiting for me for a long time?* where they haven't just shown up (late) to meet somebody and asked them if they'd been waiting in the present.

Comment: @Jason Bassford I can. A girl asks her newly husband.

Comment: The answer -- and it doesn't apply only to tenses, which have very little to do with time anyway -- is that people guess. The speaker guesses which way to say it, and the addressee guesses about what the speaker is intending to mean; and they're both frequently wrong. People make mistakes, of all kinds, which is why language (though not writing, alas) has built-in repair procedures.

Comment: "Have you been waiting for me for a long time?" perfectly shows the difference between classrooms and, say, theatres or railway stations. There’s nothing really wrong there, but no-one would say it. They’d use “Have you been waiting long?" unless there was a special context…

“I have talked to Peter for 20 minutes” by itself can’t mean “more than once” without clearly stated extra context, such as the interrogation of a slippery suspect… but how likely is that?

Can you not find - or form - a conversation group?

Answer (score 1):

We'd just avoid phrasing it that way. Instead,

"I have been talking to Peter for 20 minutes."
 "I talked to Peter for 20 minutes once."
 "I have talked to Peter, and he said..."

"Have you been waiting for me for a long time?"
 "Have you been waiting for me every day for 10 years?!"

Ambiguity can usually be avoided in these constructions by emphasizing what's important.